How to export InfluxDB data to Parquet and compress by time intervals?
I’m a bit new to this, and I’ve suddenly been tasked with exporting large datasets from InfluxDB into Parquet format for easier storage and analysis. My main objectives are:
Finding a straightforward way to export and convert InfluxDB data to Parquet.
Compressing the data by aggregating over time intervals (e.g., daily or weekly).
Since I’m pretty new to handling data transformations like this, I’d appreciate any beginner-friendly guidance or best practices. Any tips on tools, automation, or handling large datasets would be really helpful!
Thanks a ton!
I have searched in github

welcome, read up on python influxdb-client, pandas and pyarrow; by leveraging  them you can query your influx db and convert to parquet , as for bucketing you can either do that at the influxdb side or the post processing side, pypi.org is good starting place

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
